# Is having a ref() variable in an external imported module the same as using provide/inject?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to understand the case for provide/inject.
I want to share a value between components. [I read in the documentation that you can do so by using provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html)

But... why would I, if I can simply share a common ref()?

For example:

```
///////////////////////
// sharedRef.js
///////////////////////
import { ref } from 'vue';

export const myValue = ref(10);

///////////////////////
// component A
///////////////////////
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Component A</h2>
    <p>Value in Component A: {{ myValue }}</p>
    <button @click="incrementInComponentA">Increment in Component A</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { myValue } from './sharedRef.js';

const incrementInComponentA = () => {
  myValue.value++;
};
</script>

///////////////////////
// COMPONENT B
///////////////////////

<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Component B</h2>
    <p>Value in Component B: {{ myValue }}</p>
    <button @click="decrementInComponentB">Decrement in Component B</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { myValue } from './sharedRef.js';

const decrementInComponentB = () => {
  myValue.value--;
};
</script>
```

Since both Component A and Component B import myValue from the same external file, they are sharing the same ref() value.

So... why would I use provide/inject here instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing the same variable is usually called "store" (see Pinia for example)
https://pinia.vuejs.org/

```
// store.ts
let store; // global value used by the whole application
export function useStore() {
  return store ??= reactive({
    foo: 'bar',
    get length(){ return this.foo.length },
    bar(){ console.log(this.foo) }
  })
}

// file.vue
import {useStore} from 'store.ts'
const store = useStore()
<template>
 {{ store.foo }}
</template>
```

It will be exactly same object in all the component tree.

Say, you have a tic-tac-toe game, with cell values using the store.
If you will have multiple grids, *they will have the same game state*, because their state is shared in the same store

Provide/Inject allows you to make that store local to one component and its children only

```
// store.ts
export function provideStore() {
  const store = reactive({
    foo: 'bar',
    get length(){ return this.foo.length },
    bar(){ console.log(this.foo) }
  })
  provide('my-store', store)
  return store;
}
export function useStore() {
  return inject('my-store')
}

// file.vue
import {provideStore} from 'store.ts'
const store = provideStore()
<template>
 {{ store.foo }}
 <Child />
</template>

// child.vue
import {useStore} from 'store.ts'
const store = useStore()
<template>
 {{ store.foo }}
</template>
```

Comment: Wonderful. I had missed the "descendant only" part. I do wonder how the hell Vue does it!

Comment: I guess it's reverse prop drilling. Instead of drilling props down the tree, `inject` drill up the tree until it finds the component with matching $provide

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/b775b71c788499ec7ee58bc2cf4cd04ed388e072/packages/runtime-core/src/apiInject.ts#L9

Comment: Lovely -- that's how I thought it was implemented!